# International Character Issue

Tags: java, android

I have a string with value:

`'Reserva de Usos M\xfaltiples de la Cuenca del Lago de Atitl\xe1n-RUMCLA (Atitl\xe1n Watershed Multiple Use Reserve)'`

How do I get the `\xfa` and `\xe1` to show up as characters?

Thanks
Eric

Comment: Do you want to display this character's in `TextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to fix the issue:

```
protected String FixHexValuesInString(String str) {

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\\\x([0-9a-f]{2})").matcher(str);    
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int codepoint = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1), 16);
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf((char) codepoint));
    }
    return matcher.appendTail(sb).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it in a TextView or similar you can use the following to parse as html
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Text here"));

Comment: I am trying to populate a ListView with this data. Will this work for that too? Thx.

Comment: If you use the Html.fromHtml("") when setting the text, it should.

Comment: Thank you Adam. I'll try that later today and let you know how I do. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

where u get this text from? from internet or blahblah or it's stored in app..

In last case, don't hardcode it, just save it in `Strings.xml` as "Múltiples" and pull later from there.. I didn't experienced any language/character issues using it like that, and i use spanich character without any problem. Cheers

Comment: I get it from a text file that is provided to me. The characters are already converted to hex.